# Gta 5 getaway car (blitz play)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Ok so I have to find a getaway car but whenever I go into a car it doesn't say if this car is suitable or not.

Comment: Which mission. It probably needs a four - door car, and that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need a four door and a fast car because we have to escape in hurry after the hiest ill give you  name of the cars like michell's original car.

Answer (score 0):

Gateway cars is a pre-heist mission in GTA 5. You must check the place or location from where you are picking the car up.Remember Park your getaway car close to Devin Weston's house location.